# Change link color in Thunderbird (Icedove)

Tags: thunderbird

I am following [this howto](http://ilias.ca/blog/2005/09/changing-the-link-colours-in-thunderbird/), to change the link color displayed in my messages.

I have modified the value of `browser.anchor_color`, but I see no effect (after restart). The link in my messages is still the default dark blue. (I need light blue, because I am using dark theme, with dark background)

Is there some other value I need to change?

Comment: have you tried holding Ctrl and then F5?

Comment: can you please be more specific? Hold Ctrl + F5 where. When? To achieve what?

Comment: hard refreshes the page to ensure you're not getting a cached version.

Comment: I have already restarted thunderbird after the change. Is this not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, my changes were overridden by an extension that was installed (quote colors). After uninstalling that extension, all worked fine.